# Prevent several threads from entering the same method of different objects

Tags: java, multithreading

### <sub>Please skip to the TLTR if you do not want to read the whole story but the question:)</sub>

I need to fix a bug in our system and I have found the bug but could not find an optimal solution for this problem.

As an illustration, what it is aimed to be done is; when there are three files to be closed and for each file, a different thread (3 threads in this example) is created and should get the id of the file and by using file's id, it should close the file.

However, the person, who programs this, did not think something genuinely. At the moment, three threads are created for three different files and they access to the method, which distributes the ids, at the same time and the method gives the id of the first file (normally, first id to first thread, second id to second thread and third id to the third thread should be given) to three threads and these three threads try to close the same file (which causes the bug).

I cannot change this structure and it should be remain as it is.

---

### TLTR

What I try to achieve is; how can I prevent several threads from entering the same method at the same time?

I tried synchronized (and lock) strategies for this but they did not help me in this situation, because each thread has its own lock (there are several objects created).

Comment: You need to synchronize on the same object. You'll probably have to paste some code illustrating your problem better.

Comment: Thank for the comment. The system, which I am current working on, is a legacy system and I cannot change anything except for solving the problem because it is tightly coupled.

Comment: That doesn't contradict anything I said. I am just asking for more information and telling you the gist of the solution.

Comment: @matt I will try your solution, if it does not work, I will give more information. Thanks for the answer btw.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create a singleton.

```
public static final Object globalLock = new Object();
```

Then in your methods where you need to protect.

```
synchronized(globalLock){
     //get your file ids.
}
```

Comment: Thank you again. This solution worked for me. I did not know about this static global lock. Again learnt something :)

Comment: @AdInfinitum it is just a static field that all of your threads have access to, which lets you synchronize on the same object. It would be very similar to using the `MyClass.class` solution below. Glad to hear it works.

Answer (score 2):

Couple of ways for doing this, here are some:

Make method `synchronized`

```
    public class MyClass{
         public void synchronized mySynchronizedMethod(); // only single thread will be allowed to invoke this method on the SAME INSTANCE OF MyClass     

         public void notSynchronizedMethod();
    }
```

Use synchronized block:

```
MyClass obj=new MyClass();
synchronized(obj){
  // only single thread is allowed to enter that block WITH obj INSTANCE.
      obj.notSynchronizedMethod(): 
}
```

Synchronize on class

```
MyClass obj=new MyClass();
synchronized(MyClass.class){
//single thread is allowed for this block in a scope of WHOLE CLASS LOADER so in most cases you can say it is "globally" synchronized
}
```

Use `Semaphore`

```
Semaphore sem=new Sempahore(1);
sem.aquire(); // Thread will aquire permit, another thread will wait 
//this will be synchronized block
sem.release(); allows another thread to aquire permit
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer. Even if your solutions are perfect, I needed something like a global lock, which matt gave in his answer. Because, the system creates different objects instead of working on the same object and the classical way of synchronizing did not help me. But I upvoted your answer because I think you give a very good overview on different locks.